# Getting specific percentage of data from SQL by date

Tags: presto

Suppose we have a table A with id and date with 6 months of data. We need 10% of random data from each day. How do we get that using SQL query?

Example:
table A

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10/20/2020 |
| 23464 | 10/03/2020 |
| 7869 | 12/22/2020 |
| 34345 | 08/09/2020 |
| 1539 | 08/23/2020 |
| 95624 | 08/13/2020 |
| 4690 | 12/21/2020 |
| 23581 | 11/11/2020 |
| 6788 | 11/10/2020 |
| 18009 | 09/17/2020 |

The output should be a table with id and date with each date having 10% of ids.

I tried using

```
select date, count(*) from table_a where rand() <= 0.10 group by date
```

but not able to get expected output.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Hive - please tag the **single** RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @DaleK How do you maintain your sanity?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow sonia! please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. keep in mind to use **only** relevant tags so the right people can help you.

Comment: `rand() <= 0.10` <-- Check your RDBMS' documentation to see if `RAND()` is evaluated per-query or per-row, because the difference matters here.

Comment: "rdbms" is not a helpful tag... am I in a hidden-camera wind-up sketch show?

Comment: @Dai its hit and miss some days lol

Comment: also, *"We need 10% of data from each day"* which 10%? from top? bottom? randomly selected?

Comment: @BagusTesa And why even subsample? What's the harm of using all data for aggregation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking. We need randomly selected data.

Comment: The total 6 months data is of 10GB. We only need 1GB of 6 months of data, so having 10% of random data for each date will help.

Comment: Then why not just use the first 10% (`LIMIT 10000` or whatever)?  That's just as random as a random selection.

Comment: Simply taking first 10% is not random; some rdbms engines return data in a particular order, if none specified. If this is SQL server, for example, and you have a clustered index, most of the time you will get rows in the clustered index order.

Comment: We need 10% / 10000 random samples for each day. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Using Rand function is a good start, but as @Dai suggested you need to understand if your database gives you a new random number for each row it retrieves or just one for the query (and repeats it for every row). That is why the correct database manager tag is important (see Dale's comment; where do you keep this data?)

Comment: @tinazmu, I am using presto here.

Comment: Try `SELECT rand() from yourtable LIMIT 100` to see if it returns a different random number for each row.

Comment: Yes. It returns random numbers. But I want 10% random numbers for each date.

Comment: @Sonia You haven't explained what you mean by _"I want 10% random numbers for each date"_ - and you haven't explained why a subsample is preferable to complete aggregation when it _complicates_ the query, makes the returned summaries less representative of the underlying data, and will take just as long to run (you have indexes, right?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Presto, but something like this could work (if the syntax is supported):

```
select id
from (
    select ta.id,
           RandSeq=row_number() over (partition by ta.date order by rand()),
           GrpCnt=count(*) over (partition by ta.date)
    from TableA ta
    ) S1
where S1.RandSeq <= S1.GrpCnt/10
```

So we assign an incremental number to each row randomly within each date, and calculate how many rows there are for each; and then filter by that